# TYPO3 11 Extbase access sorting field in fluid frontend template

Tags: sorting, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-11.x

I want to access the sorting field in Fluid inside the frontend template.
If I add the special part at the model, the value is always empty.

Is there a way to access the sorting values?

This doesn't work

```
/**
 * sorting 
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $sorting  = '';

/**
 * Returns the sorting 
 *
 * @return string $sorting 
 */
public function getSorting ()
{
    return $this->sorting;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I most likely does not work because there is no TCA definition for that field. If you add a column config for the `sorting` field to the TCA, it should work.

Comment: sorry, but i tried to add the TCA field and it doesnt work. Do you have an example perhaps?